# video player that shows milliseconds

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, media-player, gom-player

I need to play MP4 files on my win7 which apart from minutes and seconds, should display the milliseconds.

I currently have GOM, VLC and MPC-HC. (Note that I want to use a regular lightweight video player and not having to load the file in a video editing program such as sony vegas etc).

The closest I could get at is by using MPC-HC, adding a dummy srt (subs) file for the video and enabling the Subresync option (as shown at https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/3700). This shows the desired format of `mm:ss.SSS`. But creating a dummy srt (which should contain at least 1 subtitle entry in order for the Subresync option to be enabled) is cumbersome.

Is there another solution?

Comment: related- https://superuser.com/questions/712183/how-can-i-view-milliseconds-with-vlc-and-why-is-this-method-not-working (also on archive.org)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You nearly had it. Media Player Classic (MPC-HC) has this option already build in. Right click on the time stamp at the bottom right and choose **High precision**

[image]

Other Players like VLC, SMPlayer, Mplayer, KMPlayer don't have this option. Despite the fact that KMPlayer has literally a thousand configuration options

But the subtitle workaround works with any player. [Here demonstrated for VLC](http://graphics.cs.columbia.edu/wiki/doku.php?id=wiki:millisecondsinvideoplayer)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code (in python) to generate the subtitle file for subtitle workaround:

```python
def generateSRTFile(fileName, duration):
    """ 
    Generate SRT (subtitle) file for micro second display in video 

    fileName: "Movie1.srt"
    duration: "00:12:54"

    NOTE: ignored seconds to make the program more simplified
    """
    # get the hours, min, sec from duration
    time_split = duration.split(':')
    hours = int(time_split[0])
    minutes = int(time_split[1])
    seconds = 59 # int(time_split[2])
    millisecs = [x*10 for x in range(0,100)]

    # open a file to write
    f = open(name=fileName, mode='w', buffering=1)

    # iterate to print to file
    blockNo = 1
    for h in range(hours+1):
        for m in range(minutes+1):
            for s in range(seconds+1):
                for ms in millisecs:
                    f.write(subtitle(h, m, s, ms, blockNo))
                    blockNo += 1
    # close the file
    return f.close()

def subtitle(h, m, s, ms, bn):
    """
    Returns the subtitle block for the given parametes
    h: hours, m: minutes, s: seconds, ms: milli seconds, bn: block number
    """
    block = ""
    block += formatToString(bn) + "\n"
    time_line = formatToString(h)+":"+formatToString(m)+":"+formatToString(s)+","
    block += time_line+formatToString(ms, 3) + " --> " + time_line + \
        formatToString(ms+10 if ms!=990 else 999, 3) + "\n"
    block += "time " + time_line + formatToString(ms ,3) + "\n\n"
    return block

def formatToString(num, length=2):
    """
    Format given number to given length. 
    i.e num = 5 and length = 2. Result = "05" 
    """
    # number of digits in num
    digits = len(str(num))

    # mathematical equivalent for finding digits
    #n = num
    #digits = 0
    #if n==0:
        #digits = 1
    #else:
        #while n:
            #n = n/10
            #digits += 1

    # find how much shorter is num than length
    if digits >= length:
        strNum = str(num)
    else:
        diff = length-digits
        strNum = ""
        for i in range(diff):
            strNum += "0"
        strNum += str(num)
    # return
    return strNum

if __name__=="__main__":
    generateSRTFile(fileName='/home/inblueswithu/Downloads/default.srt', duration="00:05:56")
```

Answer (score 0):

A time consuming method to get time in milliseconds at some point in a video file via VLC is to make a fake subtitle file at/around the time in question, then change delay (50 milliseconds) to get frame time to the nearest 50ms.

A sample srt file could look like this:

```
1
00:00:30,000 --> 02:00:54,567
sup doc?
```

(to look for a point in video around the 30 second mark to the closest 50 millisecond)

I had an old VSDC Video editor (33MB), which also has a built in seeker, displays frame number & seek times in milliseconds:

```
1-Total video time & number of frames 
2-Timeline can be toggled to display video in milliseconds or frames
3-seeker
4-toggle switch
5-current position (in milliseconds)
```

[image: VSDC]