# How can I jump forward/backward in an exact amount in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have recorded a class presentation and I am copying the teacher's speech. Sometimes I need to return just 2/3 seconds or a fraction to repeat what was just said. How can I do it with VLC?

Comment: I do not believe VLC has this feature. MPC-HC has a `High precision` option: http://superuser.com/questions/964808/video-player-that-shows-milliseconds

Comment: VLC has definable jump settings, they default to 1s, 10s & 1m on, I think by default, shift, ctrl or alt + arrow key - but not an absolute GoTo timestamp.

Comment: Jump to specific time in VLC is `Ctrl`+`T`. It opens a `Go to Time` window but it is only accurate to the second.

Comment: OSX version is ⌘J

Answer (score 8):

```
VLC v2.2+ --> Tools --> Plugins and extensions --> Extensions --> Find more addons online
```

Install the `Jump to time (Previous frame)` extension. It can get the exact time in milliseconds and can make split-second jumps. 
You will find it in the View menu.

More details at the [Extension Homepage](https://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php?content=156396) and [Forum thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=100885).

Comment: For Macs: VLC -> Addons Manager ... Find more addons online

Comment: To activate the dialog that shows the more precise time, go to VLC -> Extensions -> Jump to time...

Comment: It shouldn't have been so difficult to use.